# Analog VU meter with 1 watt lm386 amp

Tags: amplifier, analog, lm386, meter

I am building a small cigar box speaker with an lm386 and think it would be cool to have a working analog VU meter on the front. There are obviously a lot of cheap ones from China which I would be interested in for this project. My question is can this even be done? Most of them say 3 to 10 watts on the lowest side. Are there any analog options for something as low as 1 watt?

Comment: You appear to be thinking that you can just directly connect such an analog VU meter to a speaker output. You can't. Not even for the 10 Watt version. There needs to be a circuit present between the speaker output and the VU meter as at least rectification (AC to DC, speakers need AC, VU meters need DC) is needed and possibly amplification as well. Also the "10 W" text on the meter is **just text**, very likely the 1 W, 3 W and 10 W meters are the same except for the text numbers printed on the scale!

Comment: I was aware I do need a driver for the meter.  Just wanted to make sure before I order somethings that I can get it to work at such low wattage.